# How can I check that whether tablet supports sim card or not.?

Tags: android

I am creating an application which sync the data of call-Logs,SMS,Calendars etc. to the webserver.
But some of tablet has not support the Sim card so I could not find call-Logs and SMS from that tablet.

So I want to disable the facility from that tablet which has not Sim card.
So how can I find that the Selected Tablet has Sim card or not..

Comment: You must look at : Android market filters..http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
           if(telephonyManager1.getPhoneType()==TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
{
  //coming here if Tablet 
}
else{
  //coming here if phone
}
```

Comment: But this will not work, in case If tablets also have SIM?
Please answer me.

Comment: THis code is not working.... how could you accept such important concepts if they are not correct

Answer (score 7):

First of all get Clear that, **Not all Android tablet supports telephony manager**. but some do,

Actually telephony is an **"umbrella feature"**, where the tablet may support some sub-features.

**EDIT:**

1. Specify a uses-feature node for every API feature used by your app. This forces you to think about what your app uses, allowing you to:
2. Decide which features are necessary for your app to be useful and mark those featured with the attribute **required=true**. **This lets Market hide your app from any device that doesn’t support the hardware features your app requires.**

Something like,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
              android:required="true"/>
```

For more info look at this [Android - blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/best-practices-for-honeycomb-and.html) and [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/five-steps-to-future-hardware-happiness.html)