# Check If the Device have sim module

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone,
         Is there any way to check whether android device have SIM module or not. I already check the whether the device have SIM or not.Using this code

```
public void SimCheck() {
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
    switch (simState) {
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
        Log.d("SimCheck", "No sim Availble");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Sim Availble ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
        Log.d("SimCheck", "Sim Is availble");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sim Is Availble",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        Log.d("SimCheck", "Network Locked");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sim state unknown or network not Availble ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    }

}
```

Now I want to check whether device have Sim module in it or not ( since tablets don't have SIM options in them). Need Help. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8396069/2562861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
              android:required="true"/>
```

to your menifest if you want your app needs sim module.

Answer (score 2):

Try : [FEATURE_TELEPHONY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TELEPHONY)

`Added in API level 7 
 Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device has a telephony radio with data communication support.`

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
boolean hasTelephony=pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

Note : "This has problems for detecting SMS capability, though. If a device has Google Voice installed, even if it has no telephony capability whatsoever, it can still send SMS. So this approach could give you false negatives."

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129536/28557